# wordpress website server configuration local system

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like develop and test my wordpress website on windows xp system.I'm unable to set Wordpress in my system, please help me to find a suitable phpmysql server which supports wordpress on windows xp. I've already used uniserver, phpmyadmin, and esy php but they are not worked well.I am new to this and any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: have you tried [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Xamp, Wamp for windows, and if you already have prebuild wordpress then you have to make sure that the migration is done properly.

For migration there lots of plugin available to that use one of them.

Or just change the host file with same domain name, so that you can test your wordpress site without any migration burden.

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami wordpress is a very easy way to get set up on windows.  It comes with the whole stack to get you set up and is installed in just a few minutes without any command line usage.   https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress